Person who says they want to help, but doesn't want to do it when asked
I'm looking for a word that means a person who says that they're here to help, but when the help is asked for they don't really want to do it

Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

A person who says they are here to help you can usually be considered a friend; however, if they abandon you when you need them, they become a fair-weather friend.
fair-weather friend (n.)

A person who cannot be relied on in situations of hardship or
difficulty
She's a fair-weather friend.
Collins


A friend during pleasant or prosperous times; esp. one who is friendly
or dependable only when it is easy or convenient to be so; an
unreliable friend; also in extended use.
[OED online]



Have you ever heard the phrase "a fair-weather friend"? A
fair-weather friend is a friend who sticks with you on good days
(hold up sun poster). A fair-weather friend is someone who likes to
be your friend when things are going well...The problem with a
fair-weather friend is that when things are not going so well (hold
up cloud poster), that friend disappears.
Beth Edington Hewitt; Captivating Children's Sermons: Crafting Powerful, Practical Messages (2005)


I would probably describe them as 'flaky'.
Merriam-Webster
FLAKY

informal : not reliable in performance or behavior : UNDEPENDABLE

From Urban Dictionary, with the highest number of thumbs up: 462 vs 26 thumbs down

A person who is very unreliable. They commit to do things but rarely follow through. They will seem sincere when they make a promise. And perhaps they honestly believe they can deliver. But don't be fooled, trusting a flake will only cause you frustration and heartache when they frequently let you down.

Andy from Hereford promised to help with the kids during the holidays, but forgot to organise his diary. Andy is flaky.

Andy from Hereford promised to spend the weekend with you, but would never commit to a date. Andy is flaky.



